# How to filter out data from array in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-hooks

I'm currently coding my portfolio website. Inside each project page, there is a section above the footer that is basically a nav to endorse other projects.

I'm new to react, and I was wondering if there was a way to find the current URL (just the extension) and exclude that from the projects being displayed?

All my project data (link, title, name, description) are organized in an array, so theoretically it would be

```
if (projectData.link != currentURL){
// pass the props
}
```

The MoreProjectCard is a component, code is below:

```
function MoreProjects() {
  const moreProjects = projectData.map((project) => (
    <MoreProjectCard
      id={project.name}
      key={project.name}
      link={project.link}
      title={project.title}
      description={project.description}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="section padding-h">
      <h3 className="mb-50">View other projects</h3>
      {moreProjects}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I can provide more code if needed.

Thank you!

**Update:**

projectData:

```
export default [
  {
    name: 'doodlevr',
    title: '50 Years of VR',
    link: '/doodlevr',
    category: 'AR/VR, Front End Development',
    description: 'Reinventing the Google Doodle',
  },
  {
    name: 'bridge',
    title: 'Bridge',
    link: '/bridge',
    category: 'UX/UI Design, User Research',
    description: 'Fostering connections between students and mentors',
  },
  {
    name: 'stellar',
    title: 'Stellar',
    link: '/stellar',
    category: 'UX/UI Design',
    description: 'Empowering families through storytelling',
  },
];
```

an example URL would be www.roneilla.com/stellar

I would be looking at filtering out "/stellar"

below is the code for the moreProjectCard component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as Arrow } from './../assets/arrow.svg';

import './../Text.css';
import './../App.css';

function MoreProjectCard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="moreProjectCard padding-h" id={props.id}>
      <Link to={props.link}>
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>
        <p>{props.description}</p>
      </Link>
      <Arrow className="more-arrow-icon" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MoreProjectCard;
```

**Update**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from './assets/logo.svg';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';

import CaseStudies from './pages/CaseStudies';
import About from './pages/About';

import Doodlevr from './pages/Doodlevr';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={CaseStudies} />
        <Route exact path="/doodlevr" component={Doodlevr} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So is the question how to filter out projects from `projectData` array where *some* value related to the project is also referenced in the URL? Can you clarify this, and update your question with an example URL and `projectData` that would be affected?

Comment: yes! sorry, I wasnt sure how to word it. i just updated the question with projectData and example URL! thank you!

Comment: Sorry, another question. You show using react-router, do you mind also sharing your Router, Routes, and they relate to `MoreProjects`? They may possibly be able to use the route-props.

Comment: just added the code for the moreprojectcards, where react-router is actually used.

Comment: That uses a `Link`, but what actually renders the Route that ultimately renders `MoreProjects`?

Comment: I just added the code for App.js, which is what renders the Route and Browser Router, other than that, MoreProjects is just called as <MoreProjects /> at the end of my page divs.

Comment: Sorry, one more clarifying question. Do you have a route for each project, i.e. `<Route path="/stellar" ...`. Your `<Link to={props.link}>` in `MoreProjectCard` implies this but I don't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: yes they will, i currently only have the doodlevr linked because im still working on the pages, but they will all have a route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your app structure, then each route renders a page component with a `MoreProjects` component at the bottom of the page. This means `MoreProjects` is being rendered within a `Route` and has access to the [route-props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props). The route [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) `pathname` is what you need for comparisons.

Since `MoreProjects` is a functional component you can use the [useLocation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook to get this information.

So given URL `www.roneilla.com/stellar`, the current matching `location.pathname` is `/steller`.

```
function MoreProjects() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const moreProjects = projectData
    .filter(({ link }) => link !== pathname) // <-- filter the link by current pathname
    .map((project) => (
      <MoreProjectCard
        id={project.name}
        key={project.name}
        link={project.link}
        title={project.title}
        description={project.description}
      />
    ));

  return (
    <div className="section padding-h">
      <h3 className="mb-50">View other projects</h3>
      {moreProjects}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @roneilla Sure, sorry for the game of 20 questions, but I just wanted a clearer picture of your code landscape.